# Zend_Layout with partial view - set value through Index Controller

Tags: php, zend-framework

I think I can't see the tree in the wood.

I'm using Zend Framework, with an layout.phtml which is rendering and partial

```
<?php echo $this->partial('_header.phtml') ?>
```

My goal is to render an form from my IndexController into the "_header.phtml" with

```
<?php echo $this->form; ?>
```

How can I pass the form to the partial view?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

View partials are rendered with a clean variable scope... That is, they do not inherit view variables from the calling `Zend_View` instance.

There's a few options available to you here:

One, simply call:

```
echo $this->render('_header.phtml');
```

instead of using a partial. This file will have access to all your view variables, so you can just assign the form to your view in your controller, like anything else.

Another way is to explicitly pass your form as a variable to the partial, like so:

```
echo $this->partial('_header.phtml', array('form' => $this->form));
// $this->form inside your partial will be your form
```

Your other option is to either use placeholders, or layout response segments. Here's an example of placeholders:

In your `_header.phtml`, or layout... where ever you want the form to render:

```
<?php echo $this->placeholder('header'); ?>
```

And in your controller:

```
$this->view->placeholder('header')->append($form); 
// I'm not sure, but you _may_ want to pass in $form->render() here.
// I can't remember if implode() (which is used in placeholders internally)
// will trigger the __toString() method of an object.
```

This has the added bonus of not polluting your view instance with one-off variables, like the form.

<del>Note: I'll link to the manual pages as soon as the ZF site is back up; 1.9 launch is today, so the site's getting updated currently.</del>

Here's some relevant manual pages:

- [Placeholder view helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.placeholder)
- [Partial view helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.partial)